# How to merge two Dataframes replacing NaN values?

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I'm working with two tables with the same columns. I need to merge them but replacing null values (identified ad 'N/A').

The first table is my reference. So in cases to different values (and is not 'N/A'), the result of the first table must prevail.

The expected result is one row with 'DistanciaPercorrida' equal to '3km' and 'TempoCorrida' equal to '4min 38s'.

[image]

SOLVE:

I used `df.replace('?', np.NaN)` to transform 'N/A' to NaN value and after `df1.set_index('Data').combine_first(df2.set_index('Data')).reset_index()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) to fill `NaN` values from your first dataframe with the values of the second:

```
>>> df1.set_index('Data').combine_first(df2.set_index('Data')).reset_index()

        Data DistanciaPercorrida TempoCorrida
0  15 de ago                 3km     4min 38s
```

Comment: Is not working... maybe because I don't have NaN values... They are indicated as 'N/A' string

Comment: great! was that!